# Why do I get access denied errors on MySQL server every now and then?

Tags: mysql

I am going through my general log file when I realise that I always get the following error upon start up of my server:

```
Access denied for user 'UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

And every time upon launching of MySQL Workbench, I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Although I have no problem running queries or updating tables, I still find those two errors irritating and would like to not have it appear on my log file, or at least find out the reason why they are there.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates that root has a password, but you are not supplying it, hence the (Using password: NO)

try using mysql -u root -p

The -p will make it prompt you for a password.

if everything working fine, then you have some application trying to make a request on the MYSQL with root username without password.

Is the Machine online? if yes do you have the MYSQL allowing remote connections?

If yes that dangerous you should install a protection on your MYSQL that can be done with iptables if ur machine is linux or if the server is Windows you should use the advanced firewall rule on MYSQL port 3306 or whatever port you use.

can u telnet your server on port  3306? if yes then protect the MYSQL... if you don't need the remote connections then simply disable it.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Remember to accept the answer that actually answered your question by clicking the outline of the check mark so that it turns green. Welcome to Server Fault!

Comment: @QuestionOverflow what was the reason^

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer:

http://osdir.com/ml/centos/2011-07/msg01609.html

a bug in the startup script